# Is there a hello-world spring security 4.0.SNAPSHOT example?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to apply spring security 4.0 to the simple [spring security project by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/). What I've done is replaced the spring security's maven dependecies in that project from `3.2.2` to `4.0.0.SNAPSHOT` and schema location from

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
```

to

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
```

as follows:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
<!-- The line below was replaced -->
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And now it doesn't work. When I try loading the login page it doesn't render actual login page. Instead it render custom spring login form. And credentials, specified in the security's config file doesn't apply.

Spring security 3.2.8
[image]

After substitution with spring security 4.0.0

[image]

What's wrong with that?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @Ascalonian I tried borh 4.x and 3.x versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With following changes I could run the example

**spring-security.xml** update the lines as below

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
```

**pom.xml** update the lines as below

```
<spring.version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>4.0.0.RC1</spring.security.version>
```

**maven settings.xml** repositories needed

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>repository.spring.snapshot</id>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Is it joke? There is no even  such a security schema.

Comment: The attribute in `xsi:schemaLocation` is a hint, so it must not necessarily exists. Have a look here http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_schemaLocation
A copy of the file can be found in `spring-security-config-4.0.0.RC1.jar`in the path `org/springframework/security/config`.

Comment: Yes, I know what for the schemaLocation is used. But the SAXParser will throw an exception if we provide invalid xml-configuration. But now, I changed one with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd` again and it works. Thank you, in any way :). BTW, What is the csrf tag used for?

Comment: For [CSRF - Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) Have a look here as entry point http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf